# I tried to follow Spring Petclinic Rest but ends up in object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

First of all, I understand that I can't use unmanaged entity without merging the entity first.  What puzzled me is how https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-rest can persist `Visit` entity with relation to `Pet` where the `Pet` is not a managed entity.  As far as I read from the code, `Pet` is just an object deserialized from JSON request.  There is no `cascade` at all in `Visit.pet`, just a plain `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn`.  But when I tried to persit the `Visit`, it is working!

Then, I tried to apply the same pattern to my Spring Boot based project by adding `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColum` to `customer` property of `Invoice`.  The `customer` here is an object deserialized by Jackson sent by Angular 2 service.  Since `customer` is not merged, when I save the `invoice`, I got this error: `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`.

I can just add `CustomerRepository.findById()` to retrieve the attached instance of `customer` before saving the `invoice`.  But if I have too many related entities, I'll end up with many different kind of repositories inside my `CustomerService`.  I like the way https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-rest handles save just by calling `visitRepository.save(visit)`.  What makes it works?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, in my code, `customer` has `@Version` property.  The JSON request sent from frontend doesn't have this property set so Hibernate tries to create new entity.